# prepend $ to a string to make it a variable

Tags: php

How do I prepend the $ sign to a string to make it a variable?

```
Eg: 
$consumer = array()
$industrial = array()//These 2 are in a separate include file.

$var = $_GET['val'] // value here is 'consumer'

function ('$'.$var,$bar) //I'm trying to make consumer -> $consumer
```

Comment: You're missing every single semicolon.

Comment: Make sure that you apply a whitelist on this, otherwise users can freely access your internal PHP variables causing possible security breaches.

Comment: Please do not start that semicolon discussion.

Comment: Although there are ways to do that, it is usually not the best idea. If you share more context about what you are trying to do, you may get better suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$consumer = array()
$industrial = array()//These 2 are in a separate include file.

$var = $_GET['val'] // value here is 'consumer'

function ($$var,$bar) //I'm trying to make consumer -> $consumer
```

Don't forget to check that the value of $_GET['val'] is a value you (the programmer) expect and nothing else.

Comment: $var = (in_array($whitelist, $_GET['val']) ? $_GET['val'] : $fallback;

Answer (score 4):

Not the best way to reach that value, but PHP supports: $$var :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$$var
```

will be what you want.  The second $ means that the value of the variable should be used as the name of the variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php has more details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
if ($_GET['val'] == 'customer') {
    function($bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

$var = 'myString';

${$var} = 'output';

echo $myString;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's that whitelisting you should definitely include.

```
$whitelist = array('customer', 'consumer');
$fallback = $whitelist[0];
$var = in_array($whitelist, $_GET['val'] ? $_GET['val'] : $fallback;
```